# Is it possible to customize the location of DB/versioning files?

Tags: perforce

I'm using a mounted remote volume on Windows which keep all the source code. The workspace is rooted at this remote volume.

Since the remote volume has limited storage and is slow, can I store the versioning files/DBs to another location so that they are on my local disks while source code are on the mounted volume? It's Perforce Helix.

Comment: You're asking about how to configure the server? Or about how to configure your client workspace?

Comment: @BryanPendleton, Actually it is a local server in Helix. The versioning is kept on the server. So it's about how to configure the DB path on the server, which is on my local machine.

Comment: So you want to keep the Perforce **server's** data files on your **client** machine, while your **client** workspace's files are stored on your file **server**? It's certainly legal, but my head is spinning with this inversion of responsibilities! :) :) Happily, Sam has given you a great explanation in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server's files are stored in `P4ROOT`.  If you're running the server as a Windows service, you set this with `p4 set`:

```
p4 set -S Perforce P4ROOT=C:\whatever\location
```

If you're using a local DVCS server, look at your `P4CONFIG` file (probably `p4config.txt` in your init root):

```
P4IGNORE=p4ignore.txt
P4CHARSET=none
P4INITROOT=$configdir
P4USER=samwise
P4PORT=rsh:p4d.exe -i -J off -r "$configdir\.p4root"
P4CLIENT=samwise-dvcs-1509687817
```

The `-r` option in your `P4PORT=rsh:...` string is what determines the `P4ROOT` for commands you run against your local server.

In either case, when you update `P4ROOT`, you must move your files from the old `P4ROOT` at the same time; otherwise the next time `p4d` starts it will look in the new `P4ROOT` location, find nothing there, and initialize a new empty server instance.